# string week date to coldfusion date

Tags: html, coldfusion

I need to format a string date like this one:

```
2021-W46
```

into something, that I can use in coldfusions `parseDateTime` or `dateFormat` function.

`W46` in this case is week 46.

What I tried was to directly put that string into `parseDateTime` and `dateFormat`, but both gave me an error that my input is not a correct date format.

How can I do that?

**Edit**:

I forgot to mention that I need the first day of that week (in my case Monday)

Comment: Does this blog post by Ben Nadel answer your question?  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/719-ask-bengetting-the-date-based-on-the-year-and-week-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: You realize of course that `2021-W46` represents 7 dates, not 1.

Comment: @DanBracuk Exactly.  Which is why I think Ben Nadel's solution could be modified adding one extra parameter.  That being the day of the week in order to extract the exact date you want from the specified week.

Comment: It's helpful to include the code attempted, in addition to describing it. Technically you can parse that string with parseDateTime, [`parseDateTime("2021-W46", "YYYY-'W'ww");`](https://trycf.com/gist/5778abf71bdf7eb2e9313264982728a9/acf2021?theme=monokai). The day portion is set to Sunday, or the first day of the week.  Whether you should is a different question.

Comment: @SOS when I try to parse it with "2021-W46" it tells me: 
Unparseable date: "2021-W46"

Comment: @DanBracuk yeah sorry I forgot to mention that I need the first day of the week, in my case it's monday.

Comment: I might need something like this just for week:
https://cflib.org/udf/dayOfYearReverse

Comment: You still didn't post your code. Did you run the linked example or try the code in the linked post?

Answer (score 1):

Using the algorithm from Wikipedia for [calculating an ordinal or month date from a week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_an_ordinal_or_month_date_from_a_week_date) and your input format, this function will return the Monday date from the supplied ISO week numbering format passed to the function as a string.

> #### Calculating an ordinal or month date from a week date
>
> Algorithm:
>
> 1. Multiply the week number *woy* by 7.
> 2. Then add the weekday number *dow*.
> 3. From this sum subtract the correction for the year:
>
>    - Get the weekday of 4 January.
>    - Add 3.
> 4. The result is the ordinal date, which can be converted into a calendar date.
>
>    - If the ordinal date thus obtained is zero or negative, the date belongs to the previous calendar year;
>    - if it is greater than the number of days in the year, it belongs to the following year.
>
> [image]

A working gist of the code can be found [here](https://trycf.com/gist/d77435b67bab2cfd96d987b15522799b/lucee5?theme=monokai).

```
<cffunction name="weekOfYear" returnType="date">
    <cfargument name="yearWeek" type="string">

    <!--- Parse out the year, the week of the year from arguments.yearWeek and default the day of week to Monday --->
    <cfset year = listGetAt(arguments.yearWeek, 1, "-W")>
    <cfset woy = listGetAt(arguments.yearWeek, 2, "-W")>
    <cfset dow = 2>
    
    <!--- Calculate the number of days this year and last year for later use. --->
    <cfset DaysThisYear = daysInYear(CreateDate(year, 1, 1))>
    <cfset DaysLastYear = daysInYear(CreateDate(year-1, 1, 1))>
    
    <!--- Multiply week number "woy" by 7, then add the weekday number "dow" --->
    <cfset ordinalDate = woy*7 + dow>
    
    <!--- From this sum, subtract the correction for the year: Get the weekday of 4 January and add 3 --->
    <cfset ordinalDate = ordinalDate - (dayOfWeek(parseDateTime("#year#-01-04", "y-M-d")) + 3)>
    
    <!--- The result is the ordinal date, which can be converted into a calendar date. --->
    <cfif ordinalDate LT 1>
        <!--- If the ordinal date thus obtained is zero or negative, the date belongs to the previous calendar year. --->
        <cfset ordinalDate = ordinalDate + daysLastYear>
        <cfset year = year-1>
    <cfelseif ordinalDate GT daysThisYear>
        <!--- If it is greater than the number of days in the year, it belongs to the following year. --->
        <cfset ordinalDate = ordinalDate - daysThisYear>
        <cfset year = year+1>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn parseDateTime("#year#-#ordinalDate#", "y-D")>

</cffunction>
```